# Error: Parse error on line 1: in json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following json in file `mock.json`. I am trying to load it via ajax call however, I am getting this error.

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   id: 1,  name: 'My na
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

I used to jsonlint validator to validate json and getting above error. Whats wrong my json?

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'My name',
    email: 'name@email.com'
}]
```

Answer (score 7):

The [JSON standard](http://json.org/) describes properties as strings and strings need double quotes `"`.

> A *string* is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.

So you need double quotes for properties and values as strings in your JSON.

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My name",
    "email": "name@email.com"
}]
```